# django-tables2 : Error during template rendering

Tags: django, django-tables2

I am writing a simplest possible example of django-table2 
it fails with 

`Error during template rendering
In template /myproject/app/templates/test_table.html, error at line 2`

Any clue what's wrong here.  just following document.

context

1   {% load render_table from django_tables2 %}

**2 {% render_table table %}**

3

### model.py

```
class TestTable1(models.Model):
    col1 = models.CharField(max_length=1, primary_key=True)
    col2 = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'test_table1'

class TestTable1Tbl(tables.Table):

    class Meta:
        model = TestTable1
        attrs = {"class":"paleblue"}
```

## views.py

```
def test_table(request):

    table = TestTable1Tbl(TestTable1.objects.all())
    RequestConfig(request).configure(table)
    return render(request,"test_table.html",{'table':table})
```

## template

$ more test_table.html

```
{% load render_table from django_tables2 %}
{% render_table table %}
```

## Below is the error message

During handling of the above exception (could not convert string to float: 'table'), another exception occurred:

```
        return template.render(context.flatten())
```

Comment: Below is the error message:

During handling of the above exception (could not convert string to float: 'table'), another exception occurred:

Comment: Please share versions of python, django, django-tables2 you use.

Comment: Just tried to reproduce this error in a test in the django-tables2 test suite, but it passes for the whole build matrix, test here: https://gist.github.com/jieter/1173ba26dfbd883a0eb1c44b516f155b

Comment: python version 3.5.0
django version 1.10
django-tables version 1.2.6

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with table.html file. the issue is resolved after copied under /templates/django_tables/,  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem, but the answer above initially puzzled me.

The table.html file seems to be the default template that render table expects to find.  I found that specifically setting the template_name and adding the `django_tables2` to the file path resolved the issue without copying the file from the django2 source.

So applying to the example above ( I also choose `boostrap.html` instead of `table.html`)

```
class TestTable1Tbl(tables.Table):

    class Meta:
        model = TestTable1
        attrs = {"class":"paleblue"}        
        template_name = 'django_tables2/bootstrap.html'
```